# php mail without accent

Tags: php, email

I don't understand why I'm receiving on my email text without accent or confuse (Ã© Ã´ Ã£) with this PHP code

```
<?php
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$destinatario   = $_POST['destinatario'];
$remetente      = $_POST['nome'] . " <" . $_POST['email'] . ">";
$assunto        = $_POST['nome'];
$mensagem       = "Morada: ".$_POST['residencia']."\n";
$mensagem       .= "Código postal: ".$_POST['cpostal']."\n";
$mensagem       .= "Profissão: ".$_POST['profissao']."\n";
$mensagem       .= "Estado Cívil: ".$_POST['estado_civil']."\n";
$mensagem       .= "Telefone: ".$_POST['fixo']."\n";
$mensagem       .= "Telemóvel: ".$_POST['telemovel']."\n";
$mensagem       .= "E-mail: ".$_POST['email']."\n";
$mensagem       .= "Data Nascimento: ".$_POST['nascimento']."\n";
$mensagem       .= "Nacionalidade: ".$_POST['nacionalidade']."\n";
$mensagem       .= "Número contribuinte: ".$_POST['contribuinte']."\n";
$mensagem       .= "CC / BI: ".$_POST['cartao']."\n";

if (mail($destinatario, $assunto, $mensagem, "From: ".$remetente)) {
?>
```

Comment: What coding there is a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to encode a subject string and remetente name.

```php
$name = '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($_POST['nome']).'?=';
$remetente = $name . " <" . $_POST['email'] . ">";
$assunto = $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following content type instead:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' .
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set charset in your email using 4th parameter set to your [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.
try:

```
$headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8","From: ".$remetente);
```

and then

```
if (mail($destinatario, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers)) {

}
```